# How to "reinject" NavigationManager on new connection in Blazor Server App?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

We have a Blazor Server App. There is a form which makes some calculations on finish and have a loading bar for about 10-15 seconds. After loading it redirects to another page.
Sometimes during the loading due to load balancing or some network instability, connection can be lost. We have a reconnection functionality, which works good, but sometimes after reconnect the circuit changes. So it causes, that NavigationManager of component does not work, because as it is known:

"The single instance of NavigationManager created and shared per application in Blazor WebAssembly app and service instance created and shared **per connection** in the Blazor server app."

So we are experiencing a problem, that loading is finishing, but navigation never happens.

So the question is how to "reinject" NavigationManager?

We have tried:

- Make a transient service that calls NavigationManager methods.
- Use IJSRuntime to call "Blazor.navigateTo" manually.
- Google, google and google

Comment: How did you reconnected? connect again yourself or  reconnect automaticly?

Comment: We are using recommended way by ASP.NET from this doc: [Custom reconnection](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/blazor/fundamentals/signalr.md#automatically-refresh-the-page-when-reconnection-fails-blazor-server). But basically it is just Blazor.reconnect().